# Salvar arquivo de texto em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estou criando um editor de textos simples com Python e Tkinter e quero fazer uma função pra salvar o que foi digitado. Fiz a função save, mas ela só cria o arquivo txt e não salva o que foi digitado no Text. Como posso fazer isso?

Aqui está meu código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def Save():
    name = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    print(name)


root = Tk()

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=Save)

textField = Text(root)
textField.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill='both')

scrollBar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

scrollBar.config(command=textField.yview)
textField.config(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei achando uma solução na internet. Acontece que no site do Python aonde mostra como salvar e abrir um arquivo, não explica a parte de voce ter que pegar o texto do "Text" e depois escrevê-lo no arquivo criado.

A função para salvar o texto digitado fica assim:

```
def Save():
    name = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    t = textField.get(0.0, END)  # Pega o texto do textField
    name.write(t.rstrip())  # Escreve o texto no arquivo criado
```